# "The requested URL was not found on this server" on refresh or writing manually React

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404

I'm pretty new to React and web dev and have created a simple site.

Everything works well on localhost however when I built it and launched it this error occured,
namely that when I either write out the full name of the page - [www.xxx.com/AboutUs](http://www.xxx.com/AboutUs) it gives this **"404 Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server."**

However it works to access and see the page when I click on the Link in my footer, but when I then refresh the /AboutUs page the same error pops up.

I've tried to fix it with several solutions but they're either outdated or not according to best practises. As far as I understand it has to do something with my BrowserRouter, so I'll attach the code.
As said before, it works to go to the /AboutUs-page by clicking on the Link that I have in my footer.

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Frontpage} />
            <Route exact path="/AboutUs" component={AboutUs} />
            <Route path="/*" component={ErrorPage} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

}

export default Routes;

and here is how I handle the Link in the footer

```
<Link to='/AboutUs' id="mailTo2">About Us</Link>
```

Answer (score 4):

Update.

I fixed it by adding a **.htaccess-file** with the following code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It did work in my case as well, I had set up an Apache server to make a reverse proxy to the backend URL and my frontend was running with React and React Router. I have addressed this `.htaccess` file to my frontend

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are returning the static assets from you server.

An Example with Express Server

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${staticPath}/index.html`));
```